# Angular iis hosting is giving 500 - Internal server error

Tags: angular, iis

I have one Angular app and I created my dist folder with ng build --prod then I puted files inside dist folder to server folder and added one web.config file like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/kpiDashboard" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

then I convert to application in iis this is how I configured

[image]

I converted my application in iis under Default Web Site.

My domain should like

```
https://mydomainaddress/kpiDashboard
```

when I write above it gives me

> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you
> are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

and my routing.module.ts like below

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'kpiDashboard/dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'kpiDashboard/dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Where is my missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use [failed request  tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to trace requests and check which module caused this error. 500 is a general error code and cannot provide any useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing IIS's url rewrite extention to your IIS server. Let me know the result

Answer (score 0):

I have installed ISAP Filters and ISAPI Extensions along with ASP.net 4.8. I believe it has nothing to do with ASP.net 4.8, though.